# docker-machine start waiting for IP

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-machine

I know this is a very often asked question. But none of the solutions I found helped me.

Status:
Windows 7 + VirtualBox + Docker Toolbox

The Docker env worked perfectly for month. Now I didnt use it for a month and now `docker-machine start` get stuck for waiting for IP. ... Maybe I broke something with Putty or ssh cmd line tool??

- It worked perfectly before.
- I uninstalled and reinstalled all tools (Vbox, docker, antivirus, firewall...)
- tried create with `--native-ssh` & `-d virtualbox`
- deleted `.docker` & `AppData/.docker` folders
- tried diffrent memory & ethernet settings on Vbox machines
- the machines starts successfully on Vbox

-It just dont works on commandline!

```
C:\Users\gregor\dev>docker-machine env
Error checking TLS connection: ssh command error:
command : ip addr show
err     : exit status 1
output  : command-line: line 0: Bad configuration option: ControlMaster
```

-But it works on Docker quickstart-MinGW

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.102:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="C:\Users\gregor\.docker\machine\machines\default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
export COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS="true"
# Run this command to configure your shell: 
# eval $("C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe" env)
```

It would be cool to work with it. But I need 'docker' and 'docker-machine' on my command line for different scripts.

Comment: Probably you should move/migrate your question to superuser.com, as your question really cares more about how to get your Docker installation working. See: `Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User. `

Comment: @Murmel: this one might be OK, as it falls under "tools used primarily for programming".

Comment: Its worth a try, sorry, didnt want to go off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening up virtualbox; right click the VM, click Close -> Save VM State. then open up docker quick start terminal. That seem to have worked for me.